# Firebase (Flutter) - App Check fails when trying to access resource on Cloud Storage through getDownloadUrl()

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-storage, firebase-app-check

I am using getDownloadUrl() to get the download URL for a Cloud Storage resource. Recently, I just enabled AppCheck on my Firebase app, and this download URL is requiring a AppCheck token to access. This behavior makes sense, but I was wondering if there is a built in way to do this? For most Firebase SDKs, the AppCheck token is passed automatically, but there does not seem to be a built in method to get that same automatic behavior with a download URL.

I have a theoretical solution in mind, and this is to pass the AppCheck token as a header in the request for the URL, but there's no documenation on this and I have no idea what header to pass this token in. I am using Flutter, and I am accessing an image resource through a CachedNetworkImage. Any insight in how I could pass AppCheck without using a Firebase SDK would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to be able to use `getBlob` or `getBytes` but I can't get it to work. CORS fails for me.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_directly_from_the_sdk